# Indexing of 3d numpy arrays with 2d arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am attempting to extract values from a 3d numpy array. At the moment I can perform the following operations:

```
newmesh.shape
(40,40,40)

newmesh[2,5,6]
6
```

However, if I try to index it with an array, the result is not as expected;

```
newmesh[np.array([2,5,6])].shape
(3, 42, 42)
```

I have tried using np.take, however it produces the following;

```
np.take(newmesh,np.array([2,5,6]))
[-1 -1 -1]
```

Any ideas why this is happening? My goal is to input a (n,3) array, where each row corresponds to a value of newmesh, i.e. inputting a (n,3) array would give back a 1d array of length n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `idx` as the `(n,3)` indexing array, one approach using `linear-indexing` would be with [`np.ravel_multi_index`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html) -

```
np.take(newmesh,np.ravel_multi_index(idx.T,newmesh.shape))
```

An approach with tuple formation would look like this -

```
newmesh[tuple(idx.T)]
```

If there are just three dimensions, you can even just use columnar slices for indexing into each dimension, like so -

```
newmesh[idx[:,0],idx[:,1],idx[:,2]]
```

**Runtime test** If anyone's interested in seeing the performance numbers associated with the listed approaches, here's a quick runtime test -

```
In [18]: newmesh = np.random.rand(40,40,40)

In [19]: idx = np.random.randint(0,40,(1000,3))

In [20]: %timeit np.take(newmesh,np.ravel_multi_index(idx.T,newmesh.shape))
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.5 µs per loop

In [21]: %timeit newmesh[tuple(idx.T)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.9 µs per loop

In [22]: %timeit newmesh[idx[:,0],idx[:,1],idx[:,2]]
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.2 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful. Do you understand why what I was doing was incorrect?

Comment: @Jack Well without any commas, in NumPy arrays, you are only indexing into the first dim with something like `newmesh[np.array([2,5,6])]`, which would select three elems from first dim and everything from rest of the dims. So, it was essentially : `newmesh[np.array([2,5,6]),:,:]`.